# How to fetch field type and value?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to build a form using mysql/php, below is part of the code I have so far

**BLOCK#1:**

```
$proceso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // my query returns only one row

...

<form action='actualizar.php' method='Post'>
<?php
foreach(array_keys($proceso) as $key){

echo "<label for='$key'>$key: </label>";
echo "<input name='$key' value='".$proceso[$key]."'><br/>";

}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='View' value='$view'>";
?>

<input type="submit" value="Actualizar">
</form>
```

This so far is getting me a form where I'm using the field names to generate labels and input boxes where i show the field value. I would like to further format some of the fields using the jquery datepicker, but only for those fields which have a type = Date in the mysql table.

I've been trying `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` using something like:

**BLOCK#2:**

```
$fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
for ($i=0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $field_types[] = $result->fetch_field_direct($i)->type;
}
```

but in this case I can't get the value, just the type

Is there a straightforward way to get the type and value of a field?

Edited to (try) to simplify:

Let's say I have a field called `email` which has type = `varchar` and my SQL query generates one result `test@example.com`

From BLOCK#1 I get:

```
     -------------------------------
     Field-Name  | Field-Value
     email       | test@example.com
```

From BLOCK#2 I get:

```
     -------------------------------
     Field-Name | Field-Type
     email      | varchar
```

what I would like is to get

```
     -------------------------------
     Field-Name | Field-Type | Field-Value
     email      | varchar    | test@example.com
```

This is because I would like to use the field type to add a css class to the input box (such as to use the datepicker).

Comment: I'm confused... is `$proceso[$key]` not the value?

Comment: yes, in the first block of code I'm getting the value but not the type, while in the second one I'm getting the type, but not the value. I'm having a hard time mixing the first block with using `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` I wonder how could I get both in order to have something like:
`echo "<input name='$key' class='$type' value='".$proceso[$key]."'><br/>";` in a simpler pass.

Comment: i posted something below... i'm not sure if it's exactly what you want or not.  let me know, i can modify it if you need me to.

Comment: if that answer works for you, check it as answered, please.  if it doesn't work for you, let me know and I will try to fix it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**  I put the output in a table because I can't sleep...

Okay... see if this is what you want...

This is a table I made for a different SO question:

```
mysql> describe user;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| User_ID     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Email       | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Name        | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Password    | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FB_ID       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Total_Score | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| add_date    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and from the DB:

```
mysql> select * from user limit 1;
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| User_ID | Email | Name | Password | FB_ID | Total_Score | add_date            |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------------+ 
|       1 | NULL  | kim  | NULL     |  NULL |          10 | 2013-11-03 23:04:08 |
+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------------+
+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

// this came from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php 
$mysql_data_type_hash = array(
    1=>'tinyint',
    2=>'smallint',
    3=>'int',
    4=>'float',
    5=>'double',
    7=>'timestamp',
    8=>'bigint',
    9=>'mediumint',
    10=>'date',
    11=>'time',
    12=>'datetime',
    13=>'year',
    16=>'bit',
    //252 is currently mapped to all text and blob types (MySQL 5.0.51a)
    253=>'varchar',
    254=>'char',
    246=>'decimal'
);

// run the query... 
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from user limit 1"); 

// get one row of data from the query results 
$proceso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

print "<table>
        <tr>
           <th>\$key</th>
           <th>\$value</th>
           <th>\$datatype</th>
           <th>\$dt_str</th>
        </tr>  ";

// to count columns for fetch_field_direct()
$count = 0; 

// foreach column in that row...
foreach ($proceso as $key => $value) 
{
  $datatype = $result->fetch_field_direct($count)->type;  
  $dt_str   = $mysql_data_type_hash[$datatype];
  $value    = (empty($value)) ? 'null' : $value;  

  print "<tr>
           <td>$key</td>
           <td>$value</td>
           <td class='right'>$datatype</td>
           <td>$dt_str</td>
         </tr>  ";  
  $count++; 
} 

print "</table>"; 

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?> 

<style>
   /* this is css that you don't need but i was bored so i made it pretty...! */
   table   { font-family:Courier New; 
             border-color:#E5E8E3; border-style:solid; border-weight:1px; border-collapse:collapse;}
   td,th   { padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; margin-right:20px; 
             border-color:#E5E8E3; border-style:solid; border-weight:1px; }
   .right  { text-align:right }
</style>
```

So... to clarify...

You can use these variables in that `foreach` to output or use the information however you want:  (I am using my first row of output, for the user_id, as an example)

- `$key` is the column/field name  (such as `user_id`)
- `$field_types[$key]` comes from `$result->fetch_field_direct($i)->type` (such as `3`)
- `$mysql_data_type_hash[$datatype]` is the string version of the datatype using the `$mysql_data_type_hash` array at the top of the code.  This isn't necessary but I included it so this example is more clear.  (such as `int`)
- `$proceso[$key] = $value =` is your value for this iteration of the foreach statement (such as `1`)

Output:

```
$key           $value          $datatype      $dt_str
User_ID        1                       3      int
Email          null                  253      varchar
Name           kim                   253      varchar
Password       null                  253      varchar
FB_ID          null                    3      int
Total_Score    10                      3      int
add_date       2013-11-03 23:04:08    12      datetime
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I would like is to get somethign like this output

`Email:  varchar  test@example.com` 
`Name:  varchar Tess`

This is considering that my query is generating a single row.

Comment: just change the one line to `print $proceso[$key].":  $str  <br/>";` and that will be `data: datatype`...?  i thought you could figure out the way you wanted to format the output on your own since I didn't know exactly...

Comment: oh that makes sense, I'try that tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this - I was looking long for this.